# drupal 7 cron issue

Tags: drupal-7

"Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running" in drupal website hosted over two servers behind a load-balancer. The cron is eventually successful but I wonder why/how it is invoked multiple times. The problem is multiple crons slow down the site.

Comment: Check this below thread

https://www.techpond.in/attempting-re-run-cron-while-it-already-running

Answer (score 0):

If you use multi-servers, you have to redefine [crontabs](http://drupal.org/cron) and you'll be abble to switch from 1 server to the other with your cron tabs.

If you don't redefine them, DP will execute all crontabs twice (because 2 servers)